# Drivers for Nexus 4 for Windows XP

Tags: nexus-4, usb-drivers

I don't have any software on my laptop for my Nexus 4 drivers. Where can I get the driver software to download it for my Nexus 4 for Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for drivers that will allow you to connect your phone to the PC, you can install the [Universal Naked Drivers found on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1489856&d=1353189747). This is compatible with Windows XP.

NOTE: This driver is by [1wayjonny](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/universal-naked-driver-updated-again-supports-new-nexus-devices/), and works with Nexus 4, Nexus 10, Nexus Q, and Nexus S.

Comment: Is this the same as Koushik's [Universal Android USB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/)? Or rather something specific to the Nexus 4 in question?

Comment: @Izzy No, it's a different driver. I added a last paragraph in my answer. It's targeted for Nexus devices.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Unfortunately, the Universal driver I've mentioned does not list which devices it supports (the examples show a Nexus built by Samsung), but it's reported to work with many devices from XP to Win8.

Comment: @Izzy I think Koushik's driver is supposed to work, if not most models. So, I think it's better than the one I suggested. But I think this one will work for her case.

Comment: I was not doubting you, geff :) I just didn't hear about the "naked driver" before (well, I have no Samsung phone/tabby). Good to know a second alternative: in case one doesn't do, just try the other :) I just need to remember: Nex 4-10-Q for the naked... Thanks for the forum-link, BTW!

Comment: this one when I plugged in my nexus it said not recognized, I pointed it to the driver it installed it. But plugging my nexus in it isn't making a drive letter. And I don't see it in disk management either. In settings..storage..menu.. I have MTP selected and PTP deselected.

Comment: @geffchang Hi, I installed the driver you posted and for me as well, same as posted by barlop, I do not get a drive letter in "My Computer" - how can I access my phone drive?

Comment: @cerr, barlop Make sure you are using the orginal cable. If the computer is not detecting your phone, try plugging it to a different port. Try and try until you succeed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working eventually when I realized that I have to unlock my phone before I connect it and all of a sudden it started working just fine... :)